# Cannot load/manipulate space seperated file pandas with header?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file like this:

```
 445546552657 GET_QUEUE 18
 1445546552658 GET_QUEUE 1
 1445546552658 GET_QUEUE 18
 1445546552659 GET_QUEUE 1
 1445546552659 GET_QUEUE 19
 1445546552660 GET_QUEUE 19
 1445546552660 GET_QUEUE 19
 1445546552661 GET_QUEUE 19
 1445546552662 GET_QUEUE 19
```

I need to be able to :

1. Load it into python
2. give it header names **timestamp,type,response_time** such that when I do df['timestamp'] I get all the data in the column timestamp.

I have done this so far :

```
header_row = ['timestamp','type','response_time']
df = read_csv(output_path,names=header_row)
```

But it doesnt work, when I do:

```
print df['timestamp']
```

It gives me all my data instead of just the column!

Also how do I get a specific cell like first row first column?

This is my code :

The main function :

```
xlabel = "Time in minutes"
    ylabel = "Response time in ms"
    header_row = ['timestamp','type','response_time']
    df = read_csv(output_path,names=header_row, sep=' ')
    '''df = refine(df)
    min_timestamp = np.min(df[df.columns[0]])
    max_resp = np.max(df[df.columns[2]])
    df[df.columns[0]] = df[df.columns[0]] - min_timestamp
    # convert time to minutes
    df[df.columns[0]] = np.round(df[df.columns[0]] / 60000)
    plt.plot(df[df.columns[0]], df[df.columns[0]], 'x-', color='g', label='ALL', lw=0.5)
    plt.xlim(xmin=0.0,xmax=5.0)
    plt.ylim(ymin=0.0,ymax=max_resp)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    '''
    print df.iloc['timestamp']






warm_up = 100
cool_down = 100
```

The function refine :

```
 def refine(df):
        start_time = np.min(df[df.columns[0]])
        print start_time.columns[0]
        end_time = np.max(df[df.columns[0]])
        print end_time.columns[0]
        new_start_time = start_time + (100 * 1000)
        new_end_time = end_time - (100 * 1000)
        df = df[df[df.columns[0]] > new_start_time]
        df = df[df[df.columns[0]] < new_end_time]
        return df

   if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I have already define output_path so thats not the issue, the file I showed u is exactly how my file is ,I tried :

1. writing header in the file itself,that dint work
2. I tried assigning headers, but when I do df['timestamp'] I get the whole data!!!

I am not sure what to do.
Note : My file are space seperated log files!! they are like meow.log and so one,but the format is exactly the same!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the space, so it's read a space separated (rather than comma separated):

```
df = read_csv(output_path, names=header_row, sep=" ")
```

To get a specific cell use iloc (or loc):

```
df.loc[0, 'timestamp']
```

Comment: I still get the same probloem, when I do df['timestamp'] i get the whole data, I just want data from 1 column , then later do some computation on just that colummn

Comment: @LoveMeow I can't reproduce that with your example